# WordPress / WooCommerce - Cannot Get All Variation Data

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using the JavaScript WooCommerce SDK. I am trying to get a property on the **variations**, specifically the **Book Funnel ID**.

[image]

When I make a API request to get a specific book I can see there is a property called "variations". When I go inside of it all I get back is:

[image]

There are a few other properties but you get the idea. There is no property called "Book Funnel ID" anywhere.

This is my API call:

```
WooCommerce.get('products?category=19', function(err, data, res) {})
```

In the `res` I get back a list of items. For each item I was logging `res.item.variations`. Why can't I see this custom property?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why I wasn't able to hit the endpoint was because of my initial setup. Inside of the WC initializing I had accidentally set the version to a version that didn't support the endpoint. I believe I had set myself to v1 instead of v2 (don't have the code in front of me at the moment).